# Automated conversion between text and numbers in a form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

In ACCESS 2010 in a form, is it possible to have a box control bound to a table field that would present data in different format that it is stored in this table field?

If I have time duration stored as an integer, for instance 1440, I would like the box control and the form to express this number in text format such as "24:00" or "24h". If I try to do this:

```
Me.txtDuration.Value = Format (Int(Me!duration/60), "00") & ":" & Format (Me!duration - Int(Me!duration/60)*60, "00")
```

Access does not accept it because text is not a proper format of the field. I tried OnCurrent event.

Do you think it is possible?

Additionally, I would like to type in this text box for instance "24:00" or "24h" and have it converted to minutes and then stored in database.

It is like transparent conversion between text and number, number and text between operator and database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use two text boxes:

1. A visible text box to view/edit the formatted data, and
2. An invisible text box that is bound to the [duration] field in your table.

In the following example I have named them `txtDurationHHMM` and `txtDurationMINUTES` respectively.

The test data is

```
id  description              duration
--  -----------------------  --------
 1  2 hours                       120
 2  10 hours and 15 minutes       615
```

The form design looks like this:

[image: DesignView.png]

The code behind the form is:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.txtDurationHHMM.Value = Format(Int(Me!duration / 60), "00") & ":" & Format(Me!duration - Int(Me!duration / 60) * 60, "00")
End Sub

Private Sub txtDurationHHMM_AfterUpdate()
    Dim hhmm() As String, hh As Long, mm As Long
    hhmm = Split(Me.txtDurationHHMM.Value, ":")
    hh = CLng(hhmm(0))
    mm = CLng(hhmm(1))
    Me.txtDurationMINUTES.Value = hh * 60 + mm
End Sub
```

and the form looks like this to the user:

[image: FormView.png]

Comment: I did not think of hidden text box :) Thanks so much!

Comment: Just one more thing Gord if I may ask. If someone empty the text box txtDurationHHMM, how can I set Null value to the field [duration]? Both .Value = "", .Value = Null does not seem to work for me. Cheers!

Comment: @ZikO `Me.txtDurationMINUTES.Value = Null` works for me.

Comment: I've not realised I've set "Yes" for "Required" property of this field. It's all working thanks for help :)